# Keep the text meant to be displayed open instead of getting a connection was reset error

Tags: .net, go

I am trying to display the data of the get request from visiting port 8080 on my local machine and the text will display and then immediatley be followed by a "The connection was reset" error. How do I stop the connection from being reset immediatley. The following is the go lang code that I am currently using.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func handleConnection(c net.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()
    fmt.Println("Connection Handled")
    request := make([]byte, 100)
    c.Read(request)
    c.Write(request)
}

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Connection Accepted")
        }
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }

}
```

Comment: The connection is reset when it is closed by the sender. `handleConnection` closes the connection and returns after writing data.

Comment: @BurakSerdar If i do not close the connection the browser get stuck loading infinitley and nothing is shown in the browser.

Comment: Don't test it with a browser. You are not dealing with HTTP here.

Comment: It looks like you are not doing actual HTTP but simply echo the HTTP request back to the browser as HTTP response - which is not what is expected from the browser but instead a well-formed HTTP response is expected. Apart from that you only read 100 byte of the request which is likely larger. This leaves unread data in `conn` before it gets closed - which causes the connection to be reset by the server.